# Node-red-node-sqlite npm install node-gyp problem

Tags: node.js, sqlite, raspberry-pi, node-red

I am currently working with node-red on a raspberry pi 3B+. The problem begins when I try to install node-red-node-sqlite node. This happens when I try to install the nodes from node-red pallete or when I execute 'npm install' through the terminal.

I would really appreciate if someone have experienced to share possible solutions. I've been trying to solve it for a couple days now,

This is the error log:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future

sqlite3@4.2.0 install /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3

node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download

node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v83-linux-arm.tar.gz

node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@14.18.1 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install

gyp ERR! configure error

gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET

gyp ERR! stack at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)

gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.66-v7+

gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-arm" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"

gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3

gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0

gyp ERR! not ok

node-pre-gyp ERR! build error

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-arm --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess. (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)

node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)

node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.66-v7+

node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"

node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3

node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1

node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0

node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-arm --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! sqlite3@4.2.0 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2021-10-20T16_30_48_019Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

To install the node version of SQLite, perhaps try installing node-gyp globally first.

> npm install -g node-gyp

Besides, maybe you'll be interested in Node.js, so I'd like to share this extra reading for you: https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-nodejs